# TRUNC and TIMESTAMP issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

--works fine--

```
SELECT COLUMNS 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE
    AND RECORDDATE = TRUNC((TO_TIMESTAMP('14/12/2012 12:00:00', 
                                         'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                            ))
```

But when I create variable `HISTDATE` and tries to input

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('14/12/2012 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

into the variable at runtime, it gives error saying "expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER"

```
SELECT COLUMNS 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE RECORDDATE = TRUNC(:HISTDATE)
```

is not working even when same value is entered

Comment: what is variable type of HISTDATE?

Comment: The variable type is TIMESTAMP

Comment: I tried and  for me its working for each and every scenario Please check below declare
histdate timestamp := TO_TIMESTAMP('14/12/2012 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
begin
--select time into histdate from tuti;
dbms_output.put_line (histdate);
end;

select time from tuti where time =TO_TIMESTAMP('14/12/2012 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

Comment: Please show the `create table` for the table in question. **Edit your question**. Do not post code in comments.

Comment: The question is tagged as [tag:oracle-sqldeveloper] so I guess the problem is how to use bind variables with that tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the testing I have done, there was nothing wrong in the query. The same query

```
SELECT COLUMNS 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE RECORDDATE = TRUNC(:HISTDATE)
```

worked fine as part of a procedure but could not execute successfully as direct sql query. May be it because sql query and procedures are compliled in oracle

Answer (score 0):

if you can, do following:

query:

```
SELECT COLUMNS 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE
    AND RECORDDATE = TRUNC((TO_TIMESTAMP(:HISTDATE, 
                                         'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                            ))
;
```

input for  :HISTDATE
`14/12/2012 12:00:00`